Is the universe and the consciousness beginningless i.e. there is no beginning?
This arose from a comment that the Buddhist position on the beginning of such unanswerables is that they are beginningless. Incidentally, in this answer, it was pointed out that the Pali terms “without discoverable” and “without knowable” were used to indicate that there were no definitive answers instead.
My questions are as below:

Was this beginningless position a later creation and posited as a response to the question on how it all started? Any reference, if any, is appreciated.
Could this position be the result of a desire to defend why the Buddha did not give definitive answers and instead ended up in a pickle too (as pointed out by the linked answer above)?

Whether it is beginningless or without discoverable/knowable beginning, the fact is there is no definitive answers. Thus, the same criticism would be leveraged against Buddhism. Some may argue that since Buddhism is not strictly a religion or ideology, such criticisms are irrelevant.
However, as a Buddhist, I can’t help but wonder if there is a tenable/reasonable argument that I can adopt when pressed on these matters by outsiders?

The Buddha provided definitive answers to the origin of suffering. The Buddha provided no definitive answers to the origin of the physical universe.

'I will not engage in talk that is base, vulgar, common, ignoble,
unbeneficial, that does not lead to disenchantment, dispassion,
cessation, calm, direct knowledge, self-awakening, or Unbinding —
i.e., talk about kings, robbers, & ministers of state; armies, alarms,
& battles; food & drink; clothing, furniture, garlands, & scents;
relatives; vehicles; villages, towns, cities, the countryside; women &
heroes; the gossip of the street & the well; tales of the dead; tales
of diversity, the creation of the world & of the sea; talk of whether
things exist or not.' In this way he is alert there.
MN 122

I guess/speculate those who preach their personal doctrine of "beginningless" are materialists concerned about the origin of the physical universe or who believe "samsara" refers to physical lifetimes. In short, these materialists are concerned about when they are pressed on these matters by other materialistic outsiders who may believe God or the Big Bang created the physical universe.

The original teachings of the Buddha are systematic (the four noble truths), empirical (the three marks of existence), soteriological (the Noble Eightfold Path) and avoids metaphysical speculation, ontological conjecture and superstitious mysticism (Parable of the Poisoned Arrow, Acintita Sutta, Sabba Sutta).
This is evidenced by the following sutta quotes.
The Buddha was only interested in what would end suffering permanently. He wanted to solve the urgent problem of suffering, not speculate about metaphysics.

"Conjecture about [the origin, etc., of] the world is an
unconjecturable that is not to be conjectured about, that would bring
madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about it.
AN 4.77


Suppose a man was struck by an arrow thickly smeared with poison. His
friends and colleagues, relatives and kin would get a surgeon to treat
him. But the man would say: ‘I won’t extract this arrow as long as I
don’t know whether the man who wounded me was an aristocrat, a
brahmin, ....’ He’d say:
‘I won’t extract this arrow as long as I
don’t know the following things about the man who wounded me: his name
and clan; whether he’s tall, short ...; whether his skin is
black, ...; and what village, ... he comes from.
I won’t extract this arrow as long as I don’t know whether the bow
that wounded me was straight or recurved; whether the bow-string is made
of swallow-wort fibre, .....; whether the shaft is made from a bush or
a plantation tree; whether the shaft was fitted with feathers from a
vulture, a heron, ....; whether the shaft was
bound with sinews of a cow, a buffalo ....;
and whether the arrowhead was spiked, razor-tipped, barbed,
....’ That man would still not have learned these
things, and meanwhile they’d die.
In the same way, suppose someone was to say: ‘I will not lead the
spiritual life under the Buddha until the Buddha declares to me that
the cosmos is eternal, or that the cosmos is not eternal … or that
after death a realized one neither still exists nor no longer exists.’
That would still remain undeclared by the Realized One, and meanwhile
that person would die.
MN 63


The Blessed One said, "What is the All? Simply the eye & forms, ear &
sounds, nose & aromas, tongue & flavors, body & tactile sensations,
intellect & ideas. This, monks, is called the All. Anyone who would
say, 'Repudiating this All, I will describe another,' if questioned on
what exactly might be the grounds for his statement, would be unable
to explain, and furthermore, would be put to grief. Why? Because it
lies beyond range."
SN 35.23


Buddha said that eternal universe leads us to a situation where there is no escape from suffering. Eternal universe translates into eternal suffering. If there is an escape to suffering then the Universe must have an end. That which has an end must have had a beginning.
It is not a good Dhamma practice to dwell into unanswered questions. It is not that it can not be answered but it leads you into the thicket of views which are unproductive for the liberation from suffering.
For example- Does Buddha exist or not after death ? Is there self or no self ? Does the universe have a beginning or no beginning?
Put your faculties into understanding the origin of suffering and putting an end to the suffering. Give up such questioning and focus on suffering and only suffering which is causally linked with ignorance. What is ignorance? Not knowing the four noble truths.
